# how to instantiate an object even if not all parameters are passed to the constructor

Tags: php, class, oop, object, constructor

I'm trying to make it possible to create an instance of an object even if I enter one parameter out of two.

Here is what i did :

```
class BMW implements iCars
{
  private $_price;
  private $_weight;

  function __construct($price, $weight)
  {
    $this->_price = $price;
    $this->_weight = $weight;

    if ($weight === null) {
        $weight = "4242";
    }
  }

  function setPrice()
  {
    return $this->_price;
  }
  function setWeight()
  {
    return $this->_weight;
  }
  function getPrice()
  {
    return $this->_price;
  }
  function getWeight()
  {
    return $this->_weight;
  }
}
```

I need to be able to create an instance if I put the weight and price in parameters, or just the price.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: Thanks  04FS !  I just need to put a default value in the constructor

Answer (score 3):

You can either just add `null` for of the argument when instantiating the object, e.g.:

```
$car = new BMW(123, null);
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46cd960eff0530c0d0a3a384fe426cae4022523f

or you can change the constructor definition to make the second parameter optional (by using [default parameter arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)):

```
function __construct($price, $weight = null)
{
    $this->_price = $price;
    $this->_weight = $weight;
    //...
}

//....

$car = new BMW(123);
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27970a41be1ff259d112a8a1a5db0d25c940092d

---

N.B. extra note: I suspect that

```
$weight = "4242";
```

in the `if` statement in the constructor is probably not what you intended - it will only set the incoming `$weight` variable, which will be lost when the constructor finishes. I imagine you really intended to set the property on the object e.g.

```
$this->_weight = 4242;
```

(Note I also removed the quote marks, as it's a number, not a string.)

Comment: Thanks ADyson, for ur extra note :  I just wanted to assign "4242" to the weight attribute if no weight was passed in parameter

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your constructor to:

```
function __construct($price, $weight = null)
{
    $this->_price = $price;
    $this->_weight = $weight;



    if ($weight === null) {
        $weight = "4242";
    }
}
```

Adding the `= null` at the parameters, will set them to a default value if you do not pass a value.

So `$car = new BMW(25000);` will work without a error.

**Edit**: If you always want 4242 as default value, you can add this in the constructor signature.

```
function __construct($price, $weight = "4242")
{...}

$car = new BMW(123);
echo $car->getWeight();
//Will echo 4242
```

You won't need the `if ($weight == null)` anymore.

Comment: @ADyson You are right. $weight = null is correct in the signature of the constructor. Thank you

Comment: why don't do just __construct($price, $weight = "4242")

Comment: @GiacomoM Just updated it to it ;) Came into my mind aswell, good point thanks